# Javafx - Concurrently reusing javafx Service<>

Tags: java, javafx

On JavaFx a reusable task is usually implemented on a `javafx.concurrent.Service<>`.

The question is: how to manage multiple UI interactions that triggers the Service multiple times?

**Approach 1 - restart():**

I could use service.restart(), but it cancels the running task and starts a new one. This is not the desired result, as I do not wish to cancel the first one.

**Approach 2 - start():**

To be able to use start() more than once, I would have to do this:

```
if(!isRunning()) {
    reset();
    start();
}
```

But if `isRunning()` is true, the second run is ignored.

I want to block the second run until the first one finishes, so no UI interaction is lost. So I wish to block or enqueue the tasks.

How would this be accomplished ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop users from trying to run the `Service` two or more times at once, simply disable all the UI nodes that launch the `Service` while it's running. One way of doing this is to bind the `disable` property of the `Node` to the `running` property of the `Service`.

If you want to queue up executions then it depends on what the `Service` requires. For instance, does it need any input? If not, just have some `requests` variable and increment/decrement it as needed.

```
public class Controller {

    private int requests;
    private Service<Object> service = new Service<>() {

        @Override
        protected Task<Object> createTask() {
            // create and return Task...
        }

        @Override
        protected void succeeded() {
            if (requests > 0) {
                requests--;
                restart();
            } 
        }

    };

    @FXML
    private void startService() {
        if (service.isRunning()) {
            requests++;
        } else {
            service.start();
        }
    }

}
```

If the `Service` (or more specifically, the `Task`) does need input you'd still do something similar. Instead of using an `int` tracking the number of requests, however, you'd use a `Queue` (or some other similar object) that contains the needed information for each `Task`. When the `Service` completes and the `Queue` is not empty, restart the `Service` and grab the next element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I could use the queue version for some use cases and disable the button (or the control that started the service) on the majority of the use cases.